# Synthetic division by $ax^2+bx+c$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I know that synthetic division can be used in order to find quotient $q(x)$ and remainder $r(x)$ of a polynomial $p(x)$ when it is divided by some linear polynomial like $x-c$. Now, does exist some procedure (another than long division) in order to find $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ when the divisor is $ax^2+bx+c$? Suppose $b^2-4ac<0$.

Comment: You have detailed explanations and examples  on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division).

Comment: There's an example [here on MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SyntheticDivision.html) -- but its not really clear to me that it's any different from ordinary polynomial division, except with a different convention for where on the paper to write down the intermediate results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could use comparing coefficients.

$$ \begin{align*} p(x) & = q(x)(ax^{2}+bx+c) + r(x) \\
\alpha_{n}x^{n} + \ldots + \alpha_{1}x + \alpha_{0} & = (\beta_{n-2}x^{n-2} + \ldots +\beta_{1}x+\beta)(ax^{2}+bx+c) + (mx+k) \end{align*}
$$

Now if you multiplied out and simplified all of the right hand side and equated the coefficient of $x^{j}$ for each $j,$ you would have $n$ equations and $n$ unknowns, so you can find out $\beta_{j}, m$ and $k.$

Note that the degree of $r(x)$ is provided for us by the remainder theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your **divisor** is $x-d$ rather than $x-c$ since $c$ is already used in the formation of the original polynomial. You can write the **dividend** $y$ as:

$y = a(x-d)^2 + b(x-d) + 2adx - ad^2 + c + bd = a(x-d)^2 + b(x-d) + 2ad(x-d) + 2ad^2 -ad^2 + c + bd = a(x-d)^2  + (b+2ad)(x-d) + ad^2 + bd + c = (x-d)(a(x-d) + b+2ad) + ad^2+bd+c = (x-d)(ax + ad + b) + ad^2+bd+c \Rightarrow q(x) = ax+ad+b, r(x) = ad^2+bd+c$.

Comment: The question asks when the 'divisor' is $ax^{2}+bx+c.$ Haven't you assumed the 'dividend' is $ax^{2} + bx + c$ and the 'divisor' $x-d$?

Comment: I want to know the quotient and the remainder of $p(x)\div (\mathbf{ax^2+bx+c})$ where $b^2-4ac<0$ and $p(x)$ is any polynomial.

Comment: Take as an example $p(x)=3x^4+4x^2-x+1$ divided by $x^2+2x+5$. I have no idea how what you have posted can be used in order to find the quotient and remainder for this division.

Comment: I am asking for another way (other than long division). Thank you, anyway.

Comment: @ah-huh-moment. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For $ax^2 + bx +c$ with $b^2 - 4ac $>0 find the roots of the polynomial and apply the syntectic division twice in a row .

Comment: I am interested in the case $b^2-4ac<0$. Thanks.